# Angular 1.5 Custom directive to Component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've upgraded to Angular 1.5 which now supports the `.component()` helper method in the efforts to help users transition to AngularJs 2. Unfortunately there are not many tutorials out there on it. I have the following simplified custom directive and template URL. Can anyone help me write this in `.component()` form? By doing this I should get the basics of it and and should be able to use it for more complex directives. Thanks in advance.

**DIRECTIVE**

```
angular.module("formText", [])
.directive("formText",['$http','formService','$mdDialog', function($http,formService,$mdDialog){

    return{

                scope:{headId:'&',view:'='},
                link: function(scope,element,attrs){ 
                    scope.show = false;
                    scope.formService = formService;

                    scope.$watch('formService', function(newVal) {
                        scope.content = formService.getContent();                       
                    });
                },
                restrict:"E", 
                replace:true,
                templateUrl:"partials/form/tpl/element/text.html",
                transclude:true
            }//return
}])
```

**TEMPLATE URL**

```
<div layout='column' flex>
     <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-if="view=='DRAFT'">
        <label>{{label()}}</label>
        <textarea style="border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF;" ng-model="content.value" columns="1" ></textarea>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-if="view=='READ'">
        <label>{{label()}}</label>
        <textarea style="border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF;" ng-model="content.value" columns="1" readonly></textarea>
      </md-input-container>
      <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

`directive` to `component` conversion code will look like below.

```
angular.module("formText", [])
.component("formText", [function() {
    return {
      //bindings will bind all values to directive context       
      bindings: {
        headId: '&',
        view: '='
      },
      //link fn is deprecated now
      controller: function(formService, $element) {
        //but not sure how to do DOM manipulation, 
        //you could have $element for play with DOM
        var vm =this;
        vm.show = false;
        vm.formService = formService;
        vm.$watch(function(formService){ return formService}, function(newVal) {
          vm.content = formService.getContent();
        });
      },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      //restrict: "E", //by default component will E
      //replace: true, //this has been deprecated
      templateUrl: "partials/form/tpl/element/text.html",
      transclude: true
    }
}])
```

**Template**

```
<div layout='column' flex>
     <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-if="vm.view=='DRAFT'">
        <label>{{vm.label()}}</label>
        <textarea style="border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF;" ng-model="vm.content.value" columns="1" ></textarea>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-if="vm.view=='READ'">
        <label>{{vm.label()}}</label>
        <textarea style="border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF;" ng-model="vm.content.value" columns="1" readonly></textarea>
      </md-input-container>
      <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
```

I'd recommend you to go through [**this article**](https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/) by Todd Motto

Comment: I tried the above format but get an injector error as follows:Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=ourMgmt&p1=Error%3A…at%20Ac.c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flib%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A449) . My code is:

Comment: angular.module("report", [])
.component("report", [function() {
    return {
      //bindings will bind all values to directive context       
      bindings: {},
      //link fn is deprecated now
      controller: function(formService, $element) {
        //but not sure how to do DOM manipulation, 
        //you could have $element for play with DOM
        
      },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      //restrict: "E", //by default component will E
      //replace: true, //this has been deprecated
      templateUrl: "partials/report/report.html",
      transclude: true
    }
}])

Comment: @KaTech can you provide me plunkr please? so that I can dig in it.

Comment: It's ok I got it working. I removed the function and return from the component. Working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/33svc5ep/